# What are good resistance values for stepper motors?

Tags: resistance, stepper-motor

I've got some NEMA standard stepper motors, and I've been measuring the resistances of the coils to check if the motors are bad. All 3 yielded the  same result, but that doesn't mean they're right.

The results that I got for the 4 connections (ABCD) I got the following:
AB: 1.9 Ohms
AC: Inf.
AD: Inf.
BC: Inf.
BD: Inf.
CD: 1.9 Ohms

Are these resistance measurements correct for a working stepper motor? If not, what would need to change?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: +1. No idea why it was at -1 before. I also noticed you followed my Materials Modeling proposal. We are now in the commitment stage and it would be very very helpful if you could click commit! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGFkOGRlMTg1ODg2NTUxZDQ1MDVjZmQyOTg1ZDcxODQzMjc0OGIyMjBhZDM4ZDQ5MzM0MWE1YzZhNDBjMzhlYfHJBfp5EvPDPybryqjeDgXYucHU-wUv4jp4j6imjIfF0 Only 2.7% of the people fulfill commitment on new proposals anyway so it doesn't matter if you can't participate much, but it would be very very helpful if you can commit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are correct DCR values for a 2phase standard bipolar driven stepper. The two orthogonal coils are isolated.

The surge current starting and stopped is  resistive V+/R .

As in Chokes the DC resistance is called DCR.  When moving quickly to the next pole , some back EMF will reduce the current slightly.

You can accelerate more with higher voltage and thus more current but while stopped, you may not need the same holding torque , so idle voltage is often reduced to required heat rise vs holding torque tradeoff.

Steppers are not as stiff as Servo feedback motors but much simpler for open loop servo control.